# scipy - how to make a matrix with specific rows and columns

Tags: scipy

i have the following code:

```
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
MeanSquareDistance1D=lambda n,m: ((m*Lastpoint1d(n)**2).sum())/m
......

data=[]
for i in range(10,110,20):
    #mydata=list(sc.mat([[i],[MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000)]]))
    #data.append(mydata)

    mydata=(sc.array([i,MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000)])).tolist() I did it like this
    data.append(mydata)

plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

I want the 'mydata' to be a matrix or array(preferable) (i am convering it to a list in order to do the plot)  with i lines (5 lines) and 2 columns.
The first column should be the 'i' and the second the value of MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000).
I am receiving the error 'ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D'

Comment: Ok, i found it!I am editing the post

Comment: If you found an answer you should write it down as an answer and then accept it (possible 48h later I think). You should not change the title to "[solved] ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
MeanSquareDistance1D=lambda n,m: ((m*Lastpoint1d(n)**2).sum())/m
......

data=[]
for i in range(10,110,20):
    #mydata=list(sc.mat([[i],[MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000)]]))
    #data.append(mydata)

    mydata=(sc.array([i,MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000)])).tolist() I did it like this
    data.append(mydata)

plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @slashdottir:This post is 1.5 year old and I don't remember what was about.It seems that I edited the post without leaving the question.